# Data flow documentation tool

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, fields-attributes, publishing, flow

I am in the process of mapping the journey of our data through the different apps used by our service. We use an ArcSDE geodatabase as main data source.
This data is

- viewed in ArcMap
- edited with forms in ArcMap
- published in 3 different webmapping services, one of which has custom webforms.
- summary PDFs are also dynamically edited
- made available for raw data consultation (data warehouse)
- made available for download in 2 or 3 different versions and formats

I'm sure this is quite a frequent case for many of you.

The thing is, it is easy to get lost in the DIFFERENT NAMES used to describe each piece of data (i.e. ATTRIBUTES)

We need to be able to research which attributes are published and where and what are their names in that interface. For instance, what is the attribute called in the web form ? And what is it called in the PDF ?
And we also need to research, for a given final product attribute, of which source attribute(s) it is composed.

Do you know of a tool or of a method to map and research the flow of attributes through different interfaces ?

Ideally, the tool should work both ways.

I've googled a little about this and have come upon articles on Data Lineage tools. But I'm not sure this is the way to go.
I've got a draft of what it could be in Excel but this isn't bi-directional at all.